# json - Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to log in on my app, access my online database and check if my inputs are registered but I'm getting this error: Value < br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject .

I don't know why my php code returns < br />.
(I added space between < and br for it to show)

Here's my code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class login extends Activity {

    Button btnLogIn;
    Intent intent;
    JSONObject jsonobject;   

    Button btnSignUp;
    EditText txtUsername, txtPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        btnLogIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogIn);
        btnSignUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
        txtUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtliusername);
        txtPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtlipassword);

   //     jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://sql18.hostinger.ph/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=u897407316_tret&lang=en&token=6afd355a23affd65cb4d05f814cc7921&phpMyAdmin=e2ba129883c7c52bc7e30fb543d3fa1095372c90");
    }
    public void gosignup(View view){
        intent = new Intent(this, SignUp.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void gologin(View view){
        String name = txtUsername.getText().toString();
        String pw = txtPassword.getText().toString();
        String type = "login";

        if((name.trim().equals(""))||pw.trim().equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill up all information", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Logging in...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            new LogInAction(this).execute(name, pw);

           // intent = new Intent(this, UserHomeDrawer.class);
            //startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

LogInAction.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
 * Created by Camille on 11/13/2016.
 */

public class LogInAction extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private Context context;

    public LogInAction(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        String username = arg0[0];
        String password = arg0[1];

        String link;
        String data;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        String result;

        try {
            data = "?username=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
            data += "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

            link = "http://threatmam.esy.es/loginActionAndroid.php" + data;
            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            result = bufferedReader.readLine();
           return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        String jsonStr = result.toString();
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                //  JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr.substring(jsonStr.indexOf("{"), jsonStr.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
                String query_result = jsonObj.getString("query_result");
                if (query_result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Log in successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context,UserHomeDrawer.class)
                            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                } else if (query_result.equals("FAILURE")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Log in failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't connect to remote database.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("JSON", "Error:",e);
                Toast.makeText(context, ""+e+"RES: "+jsonStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't get any JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my PHP code

```
<?php
$un = $_GET['username'];
$pw = md5(sha1($_GET['password']));

$res = 0;
include "connect.php";


$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_mobileuser";
result = $mysqli->query($query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if(($un == $row['Username']) && if($pw == $row['Password'])){
            echo '{"query_result":"SUCCESS"}';
            $res = 1;
        }
    }
}
else{
    echo '{"query_result":"FAILURE"}';
}


if($res == 0){
    echo '{"query_result":"FAILURE"}';
}                       
?>
```

I definitely looked up for possible solutions but I still can't solve this. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: `Log.d("JSON", jsonStr)`... Debug the request, and you'll clearly see the issue

Comment: Run the php script. This is the output. _<br /><b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in <b>loginActionAndroid.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />_

Answer (score 0):

I hit your URL as follows:

http://threatmam.esy.es/loginActionAndroid.php?username=foo&password=bar

The response from the server was:

`<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in     <b>/home/u897407316/public_html/loginActionAndroid.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />`

Looks like you have your answer right there - the request is failing on the server side and returning an error response with HTML in it, which you're trying to convert to JSON. Which, quite naturally, won't work.

Make sure you're sending the correct request to the server, and that the server code is working properly.

Also, you might like to consider using one of the excellent HTTP request libraries available out there (Volley, OkHttp, Retrofit, etc.) rather than rolling your own solution using `HttpURLConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed a `$` on line#11.

Change,

```
result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

to,

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

Note : You are not reading the response for your php script correctly. `readLine()` only reads a single line. If your php script outputs multiple (as it is now), your android code wont be able to read it and you will miss some data.